# regular expression with egrep

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

could someone help me to understand the following regexp ?

```
egrep $'[^][0-9A-Za-z`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{}|\\;:",.<>/? \'-]' testfile.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following regex

```
[^][0-9A-Za-z`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{}|\\;:",.<>/? \'-]
```

means

- a literal `^` because between `[]`, otherwise is begin of line anchor
- any character in set:

  - 0-9 (any digit)
  - A-Z any uppercase letter
  - a-z any lowercase letter
  - any of the following
    `~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{}|\;:",.<>/? '-

EDIT: I answered too rapidely and I couldn't check with egrep.
In fact the first character in set is `^` so it negates the set. The next character `]` may be taken literally. 
This expression is ambigous and depends on implementation.
A backslash before the first closing bracket `]` must be added to fix ambiguity.
Also there is 2 opening brackets `[`.

it should matches any line which contains a character which is not in the specified set: so ascii characters between 0 and 31, and 127.

checking with
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php
and copying

```
egrep $'[^][0-9A-Za-z`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{}|\\;:",.<>/? \'-]'
```

the easiest to check is to enter a tab character followed by a printable charfor example `<tab>.` or a non ascii chracter for example `¤§`

Comment: Do you want to say that the regex requires the presence of `^` and then any of the chars in `[0-9A-Za-z\`~!@#$%^&*()_+=[{}|\\;:",.<>/? \'-]` set? Then [why does it match `ｧ`](https://ideone.com/ojvglR)?

Comment: This matches anything except all those characters, including `]`